# How to duplicate a batch of files in finder

Tags: macos, file, duplicates, applescript

I've never used Apple Script before and find myself needing to accomplish a very repetitive task. Basically what I need to do is batch duplicate and rename a number of files following a pattern. Preferably I need a dialogue box saying

"How many duplicates?"

So if I have this:

> 1-1.jpg 1-2.jpg 1-3.jpg

*(It could be any number of files to be highlighted, not just three)*

What I essentially want to do is highlight all three files then from the services menu invoke the Applescript to ask how many duplicates I want to make then rename them thus:

> 2-1.jpg 2-2.jpg 2-3.jpg 3-1.jpg 3-2.jpg 3-3.jpg...

Obviously depends on how many duplicates I need.

This is probably a one minute job for someone with Applescript knowledge but alas it's going to take me some time to learn just to do this!

Comment: The batch-file tag is for Windows batch files. Edit your question and remove that tag.

Comment: Hi guys, so I'm trying to move away from OSX onto Windows (don't sign - I heard that!) and I'm trying to work out a way of achieving this very result on Windows 10. I know this is probably beyond the scope of this orginal question but I'm *really* struggling to get my head around how Windows scripting works :(

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the files and then press Command+D (Duplicate) as many times as you need duplicates, then you basically already get this without any AppleScript. The only thing that is different is you will get more-clearly named duplicates:

- 1-1.jpg
- 1-1 copy.jpg
- 1-1 copy 1.jpg
- 1-1 copy 2.jpg
- etc.

If you want to automate this in the Services menu, you can build a Service with Automator. The Services menu is not the typical place to run AppleScripts from. There is a Script menu for that, which you can enable in the Script Editor preferences (show Script menu in menubar.)

If you want to do this with AppleScript, then you want to learn how to script Finder, which is a fairly basic task. In the Script Editor, you can go File ▶ Open Dictionary and choose Finder, and you’ll see a scripting dictionary for Finder that has the commands that Finder understands. It looks complicated at first, but it becomes clear as you work to make your first script.

This is exactly the kind of project that people do when they first learn AppleScript. There are lots of online learning resources like [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/) and others. You can start with someone else’s Finder script that does almost what you want, and then adapt it to work to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The script bellow does what you want (I think !).

Exemple : only 1 file selected '1-surpername.jpg' in folder 'MyFolder', ask to have 2 duplicated files

The result in 'Myfolder" is '1-supername.jpg', '2-supername.jpg', '3-supername.jpg'.

Of course if many files selected, each one will have same treatment in their respective folders.

```
tell application "Finder" to set MyFiles to selection
set NbFiles to count of MyFiles
if NbFiles = 0 then return
set Dupli to 0
set myAnswer to display dialog "There are " & NbFiles & " selected. How many duplicate do you want ?" default answer "1"
try
set Qty to text returned of myAnswer
on error
set Qty to 1
display dialog "Job cancelled. value entered incorrect"
end try
display dialog "Please confirm that you want to duplicate " & Qty & " times the " & NbFiles & " files selected ?"

repeat with F in MyFiles -- duplication for each selected file
set myName to name of F
set myFolder to POSIX path of ((folder of F) as string)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"-"}
set ListName to text items of myName
set myCount to (item 1 of ListName) as integer
repeat with I from 1 to Qty -- for each duplication
    set myCount to myCount + 1 -- counter of the begining of the file name
    set item 1 of ListName to (myCount as string) --increase the counter for the new name
    set newName to ListName as string
    try
        do shell script "cp " & quoted form of (myFolder & myName) & " " & quoted form of (myFolder & newName)
    on error
        display dialog "error during copy of " & myName & " into " & newName
    end try
end repeat
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks guys - this is most helpful! I'm just beginning my Applescript journey and this is a great help in learning too!